# Objective-C : appending a NSString to NSException reason

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsexception, crittercism

I am working on some API (Crittercism) to report handled exceptions in the client to server.

The client API takes`NSException` as the input parameter. I have to add some application context info string(`NSString`) also to the`NSException` before calling the API.

How I can do it using Objective-C.

```
NSString* appContextString;


NSString *test = @"test";
unichar a;
int index = 5;

@try {
    a = [test characterAtIndex:index];
}
@catch (NSException *exception) {
    // add app context to exception before reporting to Crittercism.
    [Crittercism logHandledException:exception]; 
}
```

I have to append appContextString to exception.

Comment: Can you show what you have tried and any errors you're currently getting?

Answer (score 1):

You could build a new `NSException` object from attributes of the old one, but that seems very messy. As you are just logging the handled exception, I would simply log the "app context" before that:

```
@try {
    a = [test characterAtIndex:index];
}
@catch (NSException *exception) {
    NSString *appContext = @"...";
    [Crittercism leaveBreadcrumb:appContext];
    [Crittercism logHandledException:exception]; 
}
```

Comment: I would prefer to build a new NSException object from the attributes of the old one.

Comment: @SinuVarghese So, why don't you do it?

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad,  I have only less knowledge in Objective-C, So I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Does the Crittercism console show the complete `NSException` details?  If so following @AminNegm-Awad's (now deleted) answer would be best as you can put the "app context" within the exception's `userInfo` dictionary, rather then messing with the exception string.

Comment: @trojanfoe- Yes,Crittercism console shows the complete NSException details. I couldn't see Amin Negm-Awad's answer. Could you please post that code.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad Please undelete your answer.

Comment: @trojanfoe userInfo is a eadonly property

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad Ah.  So you need to build a new exception from scratch.  Sounds really tedious.

Comment: @trojanfoe Yeah, and I do not really understand what makes the *user*Info dictionary read only.

Answer (score 1):

You have to copy it. This can be done easily. An instance of `NSExeption` has three important properties:

- name
- reason
- user info

When copying it, you can add a string to the user info dictionary:

```
NSMutableDictionary *userInfo = [exception.userInfo mutableCopy];
userInfo[@"YourPrivateKey"] = contextString;
NSException *extendedException = [NSException exceptionWithName:exception.name reason:exception.reason userInfo:userInfo];
```

I think as a caveat that you will lose the call stack. You can read that and put it in the user info dictionary, too. I do it a similar way on Objective-Cloud.

```
userInfo[@"CallStackSymbols2] = exception.callStackSymbols;
```

Analogous with call stack return addresses.

I do not think that this is very nice, because the call stack becomes a part of the exceptions's user info instead of the exception itself. For me this is no caveat, because I sent the exception as JSON, therefore the call stack as JSON object. I cannot say, whether this is a problem for you.